# How can I subtract 2 dataframes of different length by searching for the closest timestamp in R?

Tags: r, datetime, merge, subtraction

I am using R to extract data from a process historian using SQL. I have two dataframes, one of net weights (`NetWt`) with timestamps (100 rows) and another of weight setpoints (`SetPt`) with timestamps (6 rows). The setpoint is changed infrequently but a new bag weight is recorded every 30 seconds. I need to subtract the two such that I get a resultant dataframe of `NetWt - SetPt` for each timestamp in `NetWt`. In my last dataset the most recent `SetPt` timestamp is earlier than the first `NetWt` timestamp. I need a function that will go through each row in `NetWt`, take the timestamp, search for the closest timestamp before that time in the `SetPt` dataframe, return the most recent `SetPt` and output the difference (`NetWt-SetPt`).

I have researched `merge`, `rbind`, `cbind`, and I can't find a function to search backwards for the most recent `SetPt` value and merge that with the `NetWt` so that I can subtract them to plot the difference with time. Can anyone please help?

Data:

```
SetPtLines <- "Value,DateTime
51.35,2014-02-10 08:10:49
53.30,2014-02-10 07:52:37
53.10,2014-02-10 07:52:19
51.70,2014-02-10 07:50:26
51.35,2014-02-09 19:25:21
51.40,2014-02-09 19:13:11
51.50,2014-02-09 18:24:53
51.45,2014-02-09 16:10:38
51.40,2014-02-09 15:54:42"
SetPt <- read.csv(text=SetPtLines, header=TRUE)

NetWtLines <- "DateTime,Value
2014-02-11 12:51:50,50.90735
2014-02-11 12:52:24,50.22308
2014-02-11 12:52:55,50.88604
2014-02-11 12:53:27,50.69514
2014-02-11 12:53:58,51.38968
2014-02-11 12:54:29,50.96672"
NetWt <- read.csv(text=NetWtLines, header=TRUE)
```

There are 100 rows in `NetWt`.

Comment: This is utterly impossible to comprehend without example data. See here for hints how to help us help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1527403

Comment: have a look at the `roll="nearest"` argument in the `data.table`

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` has a `roll` argument which would probably be very helpful here

```
library(data.table)
NetWt <- as.data.table(NetWt)
SetPt <- as.data.table(SetPt)

## Only needed if dates are strings: 
## Ensure that your DateTime columns are actually times and not strings
NetWt[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime)]
SetPt[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime)]

## Next, set keys to the dates
setkey(NetWt, DateTime)
setkey(SetPt, DateTime)

## Join the two, use roll
NetWt[SetPt, NewValue := Value - i.Value, roll="nearest"]

## It's not clear which you want to subtract from which
SetPt[NetWt, NewValue := Value - i.Value, roll="nearest"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to give me this code Ricardo. I installed the data.table library and ran the code and I think I understand what it is doing. However it only does the subtraction for the one NetWt value closest to a SetPt value and all other NetWts are NA. I need the code to loop through every NetWt value, then find the nearest SetPt value and calculate NetWt-SetPt for each NetWt so that I can plot the time series difference between the actual net weights and the prevailing setpoint for that period.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I figured out how to replace the NAs with the last SetPt value:  NWSP<-transform(NetWt, SP = na.locf(SP)) and I had to modify the roll parameter to roll=-Inf to only select earlier values and now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using xts. Note that your example would be more helpful if `SetPt` and `NetWt` included *some* overlapping observations.

```
library(xts)
# convert your data to xts
xSetPt <- xts(SetPt$Value, as.POSIXct(SetPt$DateTime))
xNetWt <- xts(NetWt$Value, as.POSIXct(NetWt$DateTime))
# merge them
xm <- merge(xNetWt, xSetPt)
# fill all missing values in the SetPt column with their prior value
xm$xSetPt <- na.locf(xm$xSetPt)
# plot the difference
plot(na.omit(xm$xNetWt - xm$xSetPt))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Joshua. I managed to get the data.table version above working but you have taught me another way in R. Thanks for your time and expertise.